# Laplace transform of $ \int_1^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}dt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Is the result of the of Laplace transform of $\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}dt$ equal to $\frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}dt}{s}$?

Comment: Your integral is a constant, so...

Comment: ok, thanks. I just hope I don't have to solve the integral

Comment: It does converge (it resembles a convergent alternating series) and is a particular value of the so called [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html). I'm not sure if its value can be explicitly computed.

Comment: You don't have to, unless you know the cosine integral.

Comment: @David: "I'm not sure if its value can be explicitly computed." - there's no simpler/elementary closed form, but you can *numerically* evaluate it, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Note that you have a definite integral which, indeed, converges (it is a variant of the [Cosine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html)). As such, you are finding the Laplace transform of a constant function. Of course, for a function $f$ with rule $f(t)=a$, its Laplace transform is $F(s)={a\over s}$.